# Laravel, validar un campo como único solamente cuando otro campo tenga un valor determinado

Tags: validación, laravel-7

esta es mi primera consulta y trataré de expresarme con la mayor claridad posible, pero por lo que pueda pasar, disculpas de antemano. :)

Estoy intentando desarrollar una aplicación para la gestión de equipos y tengo una tabla en la que hay un campo equipo_id, y después en la misma fila de la tabla hay varios campos que definen los puestos específicos del equipo y que almacenan un integer que corresponde al id de la tabla usuarios.

Lo que quiero conseguir es que en esta tabla los campos específicos sean únicos, es decir no se repita ningún usuario en las distintas filas, solo cuando el equipo_id sea el mismo, de manera que un usuario pueda estar presente en distintas filas pero cuando esas filas no tengan el mismo equipo_id.

Los datos me llegan mediante un formulario y estoy usando para validar el metodo validate en el controlador:

```
$validate = $this->validate($request, [
                        'equipo_id' => 'required|integer',
                         ........
                         ]);
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me podais prestar y saludos.

Comment: Especifico un un ejemplo a ver si alguien me ayuda.

Comment: Quiero que un usuario pueda pertenecer a varios equipos pero que el mismo usuario no pueda estar repetido en el mismo equipo